# Using filebeat + kafka as message broker system between two microservcies

Tags: events, apache-kafka, event-handling, message-queue, filebeat

The situation is following: we have 2 microservices A and B and we want to send events from A to B. These are simple events, produced each time user makes a certain request, no complex behaviour underneath. My idea was to simply introduce some message queue client in A and produce events directly in microservice, but when my colleague saw my design, he questioned if we really need MQ client in our microservice as we already have set up filebeat on each server, that parses logs and sends events to elastic through kafka. Since we alreary log this event, all we need to do is to configure filebeat to send events into a new topic, that microservice B will consume, this way we won't have to write code for MQ client in microservice A and maintain it and cover it with tests. I tried to research this matter, but I didn't find any article or question regarding usage of filebeat + kafka stack to send events between microservices. The idea seems bright, but I never heared about this approach before, so I just want to ask, if there are any cons of using filebeat to send events instead of using MQ client directly in code of the microservices